# Aggregate values by range

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, generate-series

I have a table of users with profit and number of transactions columns:

[image]
...

I want to average profit of users in three groups - with relatively large number of transactions, average number if transactions and small number if transactions.

To get range series I use generate_series:

```
SELECT generate_series(
    max(transactions_year)/3,
    max(transactions_year),
    max(transactions_year)/3
)
FROM portfolios_static
```

And I do get three categories:

[image]

I need a table like this one:

[image]

How do I get average profit of users which belong to each category and count number of users that belong to each category?

Comment: We strongly prefer data over pictures. One cannot copy / paste from images.

Comment: I dont know how to paste table here

Comment: Have a look at the [markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-lists) for basics. You can find all sorts of tricks under [this question on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be simpler and faster. Assuming no entry has 0 deals:

```
SELECT y.max_deals AS deals
     , avg(profit_perc_year) AS avg_profit
     , count(*) AS users
FROM  (
   SELECT (generate_series (0,2) * x.max_t)/3 AS min_deals
         ,(generate_series (1,3) * x.max_t)/3 AS max_deals
   FROM   (SELECT max(transactions_year) AS max_t FROM portfolios_static) x
   ) y
JOIN   portfolios_static p ON p.transactions_year >  min_deals
                          AND p.transactions_year <= max_deals
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3ae02/8)

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
with s as
(SELECT max(transactions_year)/3 series FROM portfolios_static
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT max(transactions_year)/3 * 2 series FROM portfolios_static
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT max(transactions_year) series FROM portfolios_static
),
s1 as
(SELECT generate_series(
    max(transactions_year)/3,
    max(transactions_year),
    max(transactions_year)/3
) AS series
FROM portfolios_static
),
srn as
(SELECT series,
row_number() over (order by series) rn
from s),
prepost as
(select coalesce(pre.series,0) as pre,
 post.series as post
 from srn post
 left join srn pre on pre.rn = post.rn-1)
select pp.post number_of_deals_or_less,
avg(profit_perc_year) average_profit,
count(*) number_of_users 
from portfolios_static p INNER JOIN prepost pp 
ON p.transactions_year > pp.pre AND p.transactions_year <= pp.post
GROUP by pp.post
order by pp.post;
```

BTW, I had to ditch generate_series and use just normal UNION ALL, as generate series will not return the proper MAX() value when the max value is not divisible by 3. For example, if you replace the `srn` CTE to

```
srn as
(SELECT series,
row_number() over (order by series) rn
from s1), -- use generate_series
```

You will notice that in some cases the last value in series will be less then `max(transactions_year)`

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3ae02/4)

Comment: You get the maximum reliably if you multiply first and divide later as demonstrated in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I have seen your answer. Very clever indeed